Getting values replaced by NaN unwilingly
I created a dataframe that was working up untill i added a timestep. After that if i put the timestep as the first column the rest of my columns become NaN, and if i leave the timestamp as the last column only that column becomes NaN.
TIMESTEP:
start_datetime = pd.Timestamp("2023-01-01 00:00:00")
end_datetime = pd.Timestamp("2023-12-31 23:00:00")
timedelta_index = pd.date_range(start=start_datetime, end=end_datetime, freq='H').to_series()
Total_km                  = pd.DataFrame()
Total_km['Timestep']      = timedelta_index
Total_km['Total_1km']     = PV_1_km + EO_1_km
Total_km['Total_10km']    = PV_10_km + EO_10_km
Total_km['Total_50km']    = PV_50_km + EO_50_km
Total_km['Total_100km']   = PV_100_km + EO_100_km
# gives only the timestep
Total_km                  = pd.DataFrame()Total_km['Total_1km']     = PV_1_km + EO_1_km
Total_km['Total_10km']    = PV_10_km + EO_10_km
Total_km['Total_50km']    = PV_50_km + EO_50_km
Total_km['Total_100km']   = PV_100_km + EO_100_km
Total_km['Timestep']      = timedelta_index
# the timestep becomes a list of NaNs


I can't say for sure, because I don't have access to PV_X_km and EO_X_km, but this seems like an index issue. Please note that timedelta_index is a series that has the timestamps in both indexes and values. Try using "timedelta_index = pd.date_range(start=start_datetime, end=end_datetime, freq='H').to_series().reset_index(drop=True)" and doing the same thing.
